# mailto function display all in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

When i click on the **Mail** button, the gmail client will open, but the problem is how to avoid all this from browser URL, all these subject,To, body will display in the URL. how to avoid this? or have any security problmes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageURL;
  function code (email,br) {

imagelink = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?
chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=13&choe=UTF-8";
$("#image_url").val(imageURL);
$("#mailhere").html("<a  href='mailto:"+email+"?subject=code"+br+"&body=Click here to
get code "+encodeURIComponent(imagelink)+"'>Mail");

}


<div class="foot" id="code-foot">
   <div id="mailhere" class="span1">
   </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What? I don't understand what you want to do. My best guess is you want the mailto link not to show the subject? Why in the world do you want that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. If you want the browser to visit a URI then you should expect it to display that URI in the address bar.